# React: get state data in parent component

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 react components. in the child component i have a `textfield`:

```
var React = require('react');
var  UserInput = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {ItemTotype: ''};
  },


   handleUserInput: function(e){
    // console.log(e.target.value);
     this.setState({ItemTotype: e.target.value});
   },
```

As you can see, I am tring to update state of application every time user type something in the textbox.

And then i would like to get inserted data into the state in my parent component.

and to do this i used
`**In parent component (Root)**:

```
console.log(this.state.data);
```

but it only gives me a `[]`. I also tried  `console.log(this.state.data.ItemTotype);` but this time it was `undefine`.

What should i do?

paernt component is:

```
define(["./Statistic","./UserInput","./RandomWords","react", "react-dom"],
  (Statistic,UserInput,RandomWords,React, ReactDOM) => {

      var Root = React.createClass({

    loadItemTypedFromServer: function() {
      console.log("Hey");
      console.log(this.state.ItemTotype);

     },

     getInitialState: function() {
       return {data: []};
     },

     componentDidMount: function() {
       this.loadItemTypedFromServer();
       setInterval(this.loadItemTypedFromServer, 1000);
     },

        render: function() {
          return (
            <div >
              <h1>Welcome to our game</h1>
              <RandomWords/> 
              <UserInput  />
              <Statistic/>
            </div>
          );
        }
      });

      ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement(Root, null),
        document.getElementById('content')
      );
});
```

Comment: UserInput is child component

Comment: @Alexander how can i fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Use callbacks, Luke. That's the *only* way to pass data from child to parent.

```
const Child = React.createClass({
  render() {
    const { onChange, value } = this.props;
    return <textarea onChange={onChange} value={value} />;
  }
})

var Parent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {data: ''};
  },

  onChange(event) {
    this.setState({data: event.target.value});
  },

  render() {
    return <Child onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.data} />;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: And when you use a callback (where the child updates the parent's state), the Child component no longer needs state.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the parents state to the child component as 'props'. In the child component you can access the props with this.props.yourProp. 
This is super abstract example only to give you an idea how to get the parent state in some child component.